# 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request: on cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, http-status-codes, bad-request, bad-gateway

After pushing my app to Cloud Foundry (pushing was successful), I am getting back (by using the url):

```
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.
```

My log:

```
 2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-20 11:51:52.780  INFO 6 --- [pool-3-thread-1] d.d.l.s.service.scheduling.DataOutput    : Sending data to data analytics service...
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-20 11:51:52.782  INFO 6 --- [pool-3-thread-1] ContainerTrustManagerFactory$PKIXFactory : Adding System Trust Manager
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2019-05-20 11:51:52.784 ERROR 6 --- [pool-3-thread-1] d.d.l.s.service.scheduling.DataOutput    : Tag data could not be posted to analytics service: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at 
...
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
   2019-05-20T13:51:52.78+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     ... 33 more
```

I understand that I can't connect to 127.0.0.1:5000.

When I start my application locally I am getting the same error but I can access my application:

My local logs:

```
2019-05-20 11:32:08.700  INFO 14948 --- [pool-3-thread-1] d.d.l.s.service.scheduling.DataOutput    : Sending data to data analytics service...
2019-05-20 11:32:09.708 ERROR 14948 --- [pool-3-thread-1] d.d.l.s.service.scheduling.DataOutput    : Tag data could not be posted to analytics service: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:5000 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

...
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: The error `Registered endpoint failed to handle the request` is saying that your app didn't respond, or at least didn't respond fast enough. If the error we're seeing didn't cause a problem, that's fine. Look to see what's happening in your app after that. Maybe add some logging, enable access logging in your app, or turn up the log level to get more details.

Comment: I can't access any link, because I am always getting 502 Bad Gateway. Can you specialize the part about logging?

Comment: Enable more logging in your app, whether that's `System.out.println` or through a log framework. Write it all to STDOUT/STDERR. You can see all that through `cf logs <app>`. The more you can log, the more you can see about what is happening inside your app when a request hits. The error is indicating a response is not generated, or at least not fast enough so you want to include information in the log that would help you understand how long the request is taking to process, from the perspective of your app too.